# Using ports with elm-app

Tags: elm, elm-port

I'm trying to use ports with elm-app.  Previously I used `elm-live` and a vanilla setup, and was able to insert ports like this:

#### index.html

```
<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {

        var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen(localStorage.session || null);

        app.ports.storeSession.subscribe(function(session) {
          localStorage.session = session;
        });
        ...
```

This worked, and elm-live seemed to embed `elm.js` in the `<head>` of index.html.

When I try to use this setup for ports with `create-elm-app`, however, the compiled javascript is embedded at the bottom of the `<body>`, so adding the `<script>` as I did results in this:

```
(index):68 Uncaught ReferenceError: Elm is not defined
    at (index):68
```

What is the best way to embed the JS ports?

Comment: Is it halfzebra's library? Ports are [described here](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app/blob/master/template/README.md#javascript-interop)

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Feel free to comment and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`halfzebra/create-elm-app`](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app) project sets things up a little differently. You'll have to modify the `src/index.js` file like the [example shows in the documentation on Javascript Interop](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app/blob/master/template/README.md#javascript-interop)

```elm
import './main.css';
import { Main } from './Main.elm';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

var app = Main.embed(document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();

// ports related code
app.ports.windowTitle.subscribe(function(newTitle){
    window.document.title = newTitle;
});
```